# Ошибка при скачивании toga python

Tags: python, консоль, мобильная-разработка

Я хочу попробовать сделать приложение на BeeWare. Однако там нужна библиотека toga, а я не могу скачать - выдаёт данную ошибку, когда я пишу pip install toga. Python у меня версии 3.10.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить пожалуйста.

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1600

Comment: ошибка не с `toga`  а с `pythonnet`